# Problems with lists and Retrofit2 and gson converter use in java android studio

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I am trying to call my backend using retrofit in order to get a list of themes of a forum for an andorid application.

I have checked the url of the request and it is the correct one but when I am trying to get the content of the response I get an empty list. I have checked with postman and I get the desired result in the next format:

```
 "gaiaIkustekoJSON": [
        {
            "idGaia": 1,
            "fecha": "2020/11/19 19:52:16",
            "grupo": "student",
            "texto": "Arazoak problemekin;Nahiko larri nabil problemak ebazteko ariketetan, nonork metodoren bat azaldu ahal dit?",
            "alias": "Prueba0"
        }]
```

My android structure is the next one:

Retrofit setUP:

```
 this.login = login;
        this.passwd=passwd;

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .create();

        OkHttpClient authClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(chain -> {
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();
            Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", Credentials.basic(login, passwd));

            Request newRequest = builder.build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(authClient)
                .build();

        api = retrofit.create(EhuApi.class);
       // Log.d("pruebaretrofit", "se instancia bien la interfaz");
        Log.d("pruebaretrofit", login+"/"+passwd);
```

APi call function:

```
return api.getGaiak("student").execute().body() ;
```

API call response get:

```
Gaiak gaia=activity.backend.getGaiak();
```

And the bean used before has the next structure:

```
public class Gaiak {
    private List<Gai> gaiak;
    public Gaiak(){
        this.gaiak=new ArrayList<Gai>();
    }
    public Gaiak(List<Gai> gaiak){
        super();
        this.gaiak=gaiak;
    }

    public List<Gai> getGaiak() {
        return gaiak;
    }

    public void setGaiak(List<Gai> gaiak) {
        this.gaiak = gaiak;
    }
}
```

the beans which is formed the list:

```
public class Gai {
    private int idGaia;
    private String fecha;
    private String grupo;
    private String texto;
    private String alias;
    public Gai(){

    }
    public Gai(int idGaia, String fecha, String grupo, String texto, String alias) {
        super();
        this.idGaia = idGaia;
        this.fecha = fecha;
        this.grupo = grupo;
        this.texto = texto;
        this.alias = alias;
    }
    public String getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(String fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    public String getGrupo() {
        return grupo;
    }

    public void setGrupo(String grupo) {
        this.grupo = grupo;
    }

    public String getTexto() {
        return texto;
    }

    public void setTexto(String texto) {
        this.texto = texto;
    }

    public int getIdGaia() {
        return idGaia;
    }

    public void setIdGaia(int idGaia) {
        this.idGaia = idGaia;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }
}
```

Please, I really need help, someone could help me?

Thanks!!

Comment: add logging interceptor to check if you are make request correctly https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Comment: Sorry as I have said I have cheked taht the request is correct and I checked that the response get me back a 200 OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GsonConverterFactory` tries to map the `json` data with your `POJO` using the name of public properties  in the  class or public getter and puts the correct data in correct property using reflection.
when it doesn't find the correct property the result is just ignored.
even if you make the successful request and get the result it will just get lost in the land of nowhere.

So in your case the result is ignored because in `json` the name of the list is `gaiaIkustekoJSON` and in your `POJO` the name is `gaiak` that is why it can not map and put the data of list `gaiaIkustekoJSON` in `gaiak`  because name doesn't match now you can do three things

1.change the name of list from `gaiak` to `gaiaIkustekoJSON`

2.change name of  getter to `setGaiaIkustekoJSON`

3.put `@SerializedName("gaiaIkustekoJSON")` above `private List<Gai> gaiak;`

and have a good day

Comment: Thanks! i discovered by myself sooner but thanks for the solution!